# Discord.py Error Handling Bot missing permission

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working a discord bot using discord.py. I was handling errors and I found this

> discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

This is my error handling code:

```
@client.event
async def  on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You can't do that ;-;")
    await ctx.message.delete()
  elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
     await ctx.send("Please enter all the required arguments")
     await ctx.message.delete()
  elif isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
    await ctx.send("Member not found, Please mention a valid user!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
  elif isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("I don't have the permissions to do that!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
  elif isinstance(error, Forbidden.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("I don't have the permissions to do that!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    
  else:
    raise error
```

I also have a mute command and when the bot is placed under the role that has been commanded to mute it says, "I can't do that. Place my role above the specified role" or something like that

Comment: The error indicates your bot doesn't have the necessary permissions to perform an action you're telling it to. But you haven't shown _what_ your bot is trying to do which triggers the error in the first place

Comment: I tried with ```  elif isinstance(error, Forbidden.MissingPermissions):``` but it still returns ```discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions```

Comment: Well.... yeah, you're catching [`discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions) (which is a `discord.DiscordException`), you need to handle [`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Forbidden) (which is a `discord.HTTPException`).

Comment: Alright Thanks, and what about the second part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, but I'm hoping to find a better way than using `error.args[0]`.  If you have found a better way, please share. :)

```
elif isinstance(error, discord.DiscordException):
    if error.args[0] == '403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions':
        print('Add code to address error here.')
```